# Not able to include third party jar in Maven build

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I have built [`awsblog-queueing-1.0.0.jar`](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-dynamodb-implementing-priority-queuing) with a size of 15MB.

The build for the entire project, which I also want the above JAR included in, however is only 7 MB.

Trying to run the resulting JAR gives me:

```
 com/awsblog/queueing/appdata/ShipmentData: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/awsblog/queueing/appdata/ShipmentData
        at com.test.App.handleRequest(App.java:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>s3_trigger</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>s3_trigger</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <sl4j.version>1.6.1</sl4j.version>
        <environment>local</environment>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <build.version>1.0.0</build.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <build-number>1.0.0</build-number>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.271</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.awsblog.queueing</groupId>
            <artifactId>awsblog-queueing</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Users/abcd/Desktop/amazon-dynamodb-implementing-priority-queuing-master/target/awsblog-queueing-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This is not linked to AWS Lambda - system scope is not the way to include this, you need to use install:install-file

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary an example please .So you mean to say i need to run mvn install:install-file command ?

Comment: Refer to https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Try: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:/Users/abcd/Desktop/amazon-dynamodb-implementing-priority-queuing-master/target/awsblog-queueing-1.0.0.jar -DgroupId=com.awsblog.queueing -DartifactId=awsblog-queueing`, remove the `scope` and `systemPath` XML tags from your `pom.xml` file and then re-run your build. What's the size of the resulting JAR now?

Comment: so below worked `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\u6034690\Desktop\REPLATFROM\PRIORITY_QUEUE_DESIGN\aws-lambda\lib\awsblog-queueing-1.0.0.jar -DgroupId=com.awsblog.queueing -DartifactId=awsblog-queueing -Dversion=1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar` and i can see one jar is in m2 repo .Now i have to use that jar and build ?

Comment: `-Dversion=1.0.1` has to be `-Dversion=1.0.0` as that is what is in your `pom.xml` file; what is the size of the JAR?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes this time the size is more 18 MB .I will run and test now

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes its working ..Great thanks ..Request to put as an answer it helped me .Specially with AWS lambda we need to use like this

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`maven-install-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/) to include your custom third-party JAR into your final JAR.

Apache Maven has a [guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for it but specifically for your case:

1. Remove the `scope` & `systemPath` XML tags for your third-party dependency from your `pom.xml` file as they are not needed
2. Run `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:/Users/abcd/Desktop/amazon-dynamodb-implementing-priority-queuing-master/target/awsblog-queueing-1.0.0.jar -DgroupId=com.awsblog.queueing -DartifactId=awsblog-queueing -Dversion=1.0.0` to install the local JAR in your local repository
3. Run `mvn clean package`